# Can I modify the ShellTile BackTitle and BackContent from a scheduled background worker?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am trying to update the BackTitle and BackContent properties on the back of my app's tile to show some simple text. I can set this no problem when I'm running my app and it works great. I've started setting up a background worker project to also update this on a background periodic schedule.

How do i access the ShellTile object from the invoke method of the background worker? Is this even possible.

Many thanks
Swine

SOLUTION:

It was a bit convoluted to get the ShellTile. Not sure why I couldn't just go ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First like in my app, but here's how I did it:

```
    IEnumerator<ShellTile> it = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.GetEnumerator();
    it.MoveNext();
    ShellTile tile = it.Current;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup - this is fairly standard practice. To access the `ShellTile` you make use of `ShellTile.ActiveTiles` (In the `Microsoft.Phone.Shell` namespace). This will return a list of all the user's current `ShellTile`s. The first item in the collection is always your main app tile - it'll appear in the list even if the user doesn't have your application pinned to the start screen. You'll have to come up with your own scheme of identifying which tile is which as the only identifier is the `NavigationUri`.

It's worth noting that, as per [Unsupported APIs for Background Agents for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202962%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), you can only make use of `Update()`, `Delete()` and `ActiveTiles` from the `ShellTile` class.